# Combine Multiple Param Decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to combine multiple Parameter Decorator for my application.
In my application there are several custom decorators.
My Sample Controller.

```
@Controller('api')
export class MyController {
    @Get('mainresponse')
    public getResponse(
        @Query() query: Partial<IBean>,
        @Headers('user-agent') userAgent: string,
        @MyFirstDocrator() firstDecorator: string,
        @MySecondDocrator() secondDecorator: string,
        @Headers('Referer') referer: string,
        @Cookies('session') sessionId?: string,
    ): Observable<IResponse> {
    ......
    }
}
```

I am trying to combine these decorators into 1 and return an object with all the decorators value.
Something like this

```
  @Get('mainresponse')
  public getResponse(
    @MyCombinedDecorator() decorator: any
  ): Observable<IResponse> {
 
  ......
  }
```

But when I am using applyDecorators it is giving me the return value of the last passed decorator.

```
export const MyCombinedDecorator = () => applyDecorators(Headers('user-agent') as PropertyDecorator, MyFirstDocrator() as PropertyDecorator, Query() as PropertyDecorator);
```